# My files have become folders with the actual file and a "$Zone.Identifier$$DATA" file in them

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I reinstalled windows 10 and not many of the files that I backed up have become folders.

For example: 
File used to be "index.hmtml". Now this file has become a folder called "index html" with two files in it. The "index.hml" file I'm looking for and a file called "$Zone.Identifier$$DATA"

Why did this happen? What can I do to fix this?

I could fix it by hand but there are thousands of files. IS there a way to make a batch script to handle this?

Thank alot. I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2018 and I just reinstalled from the same version.

Edit 1: I have not modified any group policies.

Edit 2: Providing more information:
Here is an example of how these files are stored:

```
DSCN5330.JPG (this is a folder)
    --> $Zone.Identifier$$DATA
    --> DSCN5330.JPG (this is the original file)

lynn2010.pdf
    --> $Zone.Identifier$$DATA
    --> lynn2010.pdf

Mass_Media_final.doc
    --> $Zone.Identifier$$DATA
    --> Mass_Media_final.doc
```

These files are all stored on my desktop and like this, I have many files in several other locations, however these directories are not to deep so I could easily place a script in a parent directory and execute it for all subfolders.

I admit that maybe my way of performing the backup of my files was the problem: I used Windows easy transfer for years to quickly backup files and move them to new installations. Since WET is no longer supported just copied with migwiz folder from win7 and used it on win 10. I actually got the idea from Spiceworks but I've only ever tried it for win7->win10, never win10->win10. I'm guessing Windows 10 adds new data or something, which is why wet has trouble creating these files properly. 
I restored the files, by extracting them from the mig file and in that file they are also in the same way. So the damage is done I guess. no turning back now.

Comment: Have you installed a program that might do this as Windows doesn't show this information. Files can have multiple streams, so they are like folders. This stream `$Zone.Identifier$$DATA` means the file was downloaded from the internet.

Comment: I have not. This is a fresh install of windows. Do you know of a program that could reverse this?

Comment: I don't know of a program that can do that. Only the console can display alternative streams. EG `Dir /r "%userprofile%\3D Objects"` To look at what is in it `notepad  "%userprofile%\3D Objects\Bulldozer.3mf:Zone.Identifier"`.

Comment: This stream is added to files from the internet. Its normal behaviour is if double clicked some warning message comes up. The normal way to hide warning message is to right click, Properties, Unblock. If they were backed up files then probably your backup program did it, trying not to  lose data. EG you cannot write multiple streams to a USB key.

Comment: I wish it was as simple as selecting all the files and deleting them, but the problem I have is that all these files have become folders so I would have to go folder by folder deleting the stream and then moving the original file up on directory. A script would be an easy way to do this I'm guessing.

Comment: Should be easy to script in PowerShell with more info. Are all these folders in a single parent, etc? Edit your question with some full paths, etc. Usually, files with Zone Identifers are found in Downloads. Is that the case here?

Comment: Did you back up these files, if so how and how did you restore them?

Comment: Kieth, Mark. I've added as much information as possible. If there is anything else do let me know please. Thanks

Comment: It's solvable but its now nighttime where I am. I can't do anything till tomorrow. If it makes you happier you can get rid of the alternative streams (now turned into files) by `del "C:\$Zone.Identifier$$DATA" /s /a"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a fun little challenge. Getting files with a matching foldername was easy:

```
gci -File -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -Like $_.Directory.Name}
```

But moving the files to their grandparent directory is complicated by the folders with filenames. So the solution was to rename the files when moving. I prepended an arbitrary string of `'qqq'`:

```
gci -File -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -Like $_.Directory.Name} |
% {Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination ($_.Directory.Parent.FullName + '\' +'qqq' + $_.Name ) -PassThru }
```

I always try to keep the pipeline flowing, but when I added:

### Recursion + modification + pipeline = Weirdness

**EDIT: Naturally, I found the soultion to the issues with this code shortly after posting...
Parenthesis!!!

EDIT 2: Working, formatted. pipelined code at the end of this post.**

```
( gci -File -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -Like $_.Directory.Name } ) |
...
```

```
gci -File -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -Like $_.Directory.Name } |
% { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination ( $_.Directory.Parent.FullName + '\' +'qqq' + $_.Name ) -PassThru } |
% { 
REmove-Item ( $_.FullName -replace 'qqq' )
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( $_.Name -replace 'qqq' )
}
```

All sorts of errors reared their ugly heads! Even after fixing syntax and some `Name` vs. `FullName` confustion, I was getting `Get-ChildItem` errors. I rembembered that I'd seen it have issues before when you combine recursion with modification, things can get weird. So I broke it down, which not only eliminated the errors, but made it easier to get the necessary paths. So this works well. The only location-dependent lines are the first two, with no path specifed for `Get-ChildItem`. You should execute `$Source = ...` seperately and verify it's contents. But hopefully you don't make a habit of naming folders with an extension. :D

### Working Code

```
Get-ChildItem '$Zone.Identifier$$DATA' -recurse -force | Remove-Item -Force
$Source = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -Like $_.Directory.Name}
$Moved  = $Source | % {
    $Splat = @{
        'Path'        = $_.FullName;
        'Destination' = ('{0}\qqq{1}' -f $_.Directory.Parent.FullName, $_.Name);
        'PassThru'    = $True
    }
    Move-Item @Splat
}
Remove-Item $Source.DirectoryName
$Moved | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.FullName -replace 'qqq' }
```

### Working Code, pure pipeline:

```
( Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | ? { $_.Name -Like $_.Directory.Name } ) | % {
    $Splat = @{
        'Path'        = $_.FullName;
        'Destination' = ('{0}\qqq{1}' -f $_.Directory.Parent.FullName, $_.Name);
        'PassThru'    = $True
    }
    Move-Item @Splat
} | %{ 
    Remove-Item ($_.FullName -replace 'qqq')
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ( $_.Name -replace 'qqq' )
}
```

Comment: The code worked well but failed for some instances like long names and a few other places but I should be able to fix it manually or maybe figure out whats wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I think its the wild card because it seems to fail with filenames that also have special characters like ñ. Æ. etc

Comment: Most likely there are filenames with `{[($))]}` or other charaters are causing problems. What cmdlet generated the error --  `Move-Item`? Try changeing `-Path` to `-LiteralPath` in the `$Splat` declaration.